# How do you say 'tidy up'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How could the verb phrase 'tidy up' be put in Latin please?

Comment: There are quite a number of Latin verbs with meanings around cleaning, all used differently. When you refer to the action of "tidying up", who is performing the action, who is the recipient of the action, is it figurative or literal, etc.?

Comment: It is entirely literal  - for a group of people who need to tidy up a room, as in put away and also throw away rubbish, as you would tidying a bedroom. I think the suggestion below will work fine. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The phrase 'tidy up' usually means 'return things to their proper places'. It may also, of course, include removing all the detritus of some operation.

In English we might say 'clear away'  or 'sweep out', and 'tidy up'. If this is what you are looking for, then the verb *verro, verri, versum* is appropriate for both clearing and sweeping. The best option for making tidy, or 'putting things back (in their places)', is *repono, reposui, repositum*.

You could expand on the simple *repono* by adding *in loca propria*, 'in the proper places'. The context will decide if you need to do this.

Comment: That is so useful, thank you. All I could find was that a late Latin word for the adj 'tidy' is ''mundus', but your verb choice w 'in loco propria' will be much better. I was being entirely literal.

Comment: I believe it should be in locīs propriīs, since the neuter plural is for geographic locations.

Comment: @NathanKendrick in that case it should be *in locos proprios*, since the ablative is for stationary locations, and here you need the accusative for a directed motion.

Comment: @LornaEllis, *Mundus* is indeed a good choice for "tidy", and if you wanted to link it directly to a verb, you could use *mundare*, which can also mean to prune or to purge or just get rid of whatever does not belong. In general I prefer Tom Cotton's suggestion, but *mundare* has its uses.

Comment: @gmvh For reasons not entirely clear to me, *pono* and friends actually prefer the ablative regardless (https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=lsn41210). I would guess it has a causative explanation, like English *set:* you can set something on a table, but you can't set something *onto* a table, because etymologically *set* means 'cause to sit'.